# HTML link not working in wp mail

Tags: wordpress

I have set a wp mail function and on the body there is a link like

```
$to = $email;
$subject = "Payment Receipt - ".$fname.' '.$lname.' - '.date("m-d-Y"); 
$bodyadmin = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>Thank you for your 
payment please click <a href='https://www.google.com/'>Here</a></body> 
</html>";
$headersadmin  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headersadmin .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headersadmin .= 'From: ABC <abc@abc.com>' . "\r\n";
$headersadmin .= 'Cc: abc@abc.com' . "\r\n";
wp_mail( $to, $subject, $bodyadmin, $headersadmin );
```

But when i am trying to send mail the mail is not going. Can anyone please advise me why it is not working?

Comment: first try sending email using smtp plugin, lets check if the test email sent from that plugin, first let me ask one question, is the email not sending or href link not working in email ?

Comment: Email is not sending, without link email is sending.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your body to

```html
$bodyadmin = "<h3>Thank you for your 
payment please click <a href='https://www.google.com/'>Here</a></h3>";
```

And it is good to use array type for headers as it will improve the clarity of your code and make it less error prone. For eg.

```html
$headers[] = 'From: Me Myself <me@example.net>';
$headers[] = 'Cc: John Q Codex <jqc@wordpress.org>';
$headers[] = 'Cc: iluvwp@wordpress.org'; // note you can just use a simple email address
```

Comment: the headers array would look better as follows `$headers = array('one','two');` imho

Answer (score 0):

You can try following Example and try it:

```
$to = 'sendto@example.com';
$subject = 'The subject';
$body = 'The email body content';
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any error in code and it does work on my side. (screenshots available below for reference)

**Problem:**

The SMTP is not configured for your wordpress site. Please try any [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/smtp/) to configure SMTP OR follow this [tutorial](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-use-smtp-server-to-send-wordpress-emails/).

**Code:**

[image]

**Mailbox:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you have concatenation bug in your code, use this

```
$to = $email;
$subject = "Payment Receipt - ".$fname." ".$lname." - ".date('m-d-Y'); 
$bodyadmin = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>Thank you for your 
payment please click <a href='https://www.google.com/'>Here</a></body> 
</html>";
$headersadmin  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headersadmin .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headersadmin .= 'From: ABC <abc@abc.com>' . "\r\n";
$headersadmin .= 'Cc: abc@abc.com' . "\r\n";
wp_mail( $to, $subject, $bodyadmin, $headersadmin );
```